# Are there any workarounds for the 1 HP bug?

Tags: pokemon-go

Last night I was playing some Go and I found a gym nearby that I could easily take.
Both times I tried fighting it though, the battle timed out because I could not reduce the gym's final mon to 0 HP - it was stubbornly stuck on 1 HP. After speaking to some of my friends, this seems to be a common bug, but it's pretty disheartening for an aspiring gym leader.

While we wait for Niantic to take care of this, are there any workarounds trainers can use to defeat gym leaders?

Comment: Try leaving the gym's range while you're stuck on the 1HP bug. Not sure if it's related, but every time I have done so, the fight has resolved

Comment: Please report this bug to Niantic , tell them to fix it. https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=319988

Comment: The 1HP bug has now been fixed.

Comment: @Praxeolitic that's great news if it's true, but I don't see anything specific in the patch notes - do you have a credible source?

Comment: I don't have an official source -- didn't know patch notes were available -- but there was a Reddit thread with several users reporting it fixed and that has been my experience too.

Comment: @Praxeolitic That'll have to do for now. Admittedly the patch notes aren't useful - thanks for your input!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 1HP bug is a result of the servers malfunctioning and not responding to events fast enough (probably as a result of latency and/or server overloads on Niantic's end).

As this is a serverside problem, there is no way for a Trainer to patch and/or otherwise work around the problem at hand.

I would suggest filing a "High Priority" bug report to Niantic through the Settings menu. However, I believe that they are plenty aware of this bug and are attempting to fix it currently.

Comment: side note on your last point, if everyone assumes that everyone else would have reported the bug already, then no one ends up reporting it.

Comment: @Aequitas Fair enough, but one can safely assume that people not on SE have reported the bug, as well as the fact that Niantic is aware of it.

Comment: It is not in their list of known bugs (as of yesterday anyway), but it doesn't hurt for more people to report.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when there are server issues, unfortunately we can do nothing but hope Niantic will upgrade their servers.